# One caption in listoffigures for a ContinuedFloat

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, subfloats

I am using the `\ContinuedFloat` command of the `subfig` package to print a series of figures in more than one page. I would like to have one caption in the List of Figures and "compress" the pages so that only the first and the last are shown.

EDIT: Since I am using also the `cleveref` package, I would like to have a link for both the pages. So it should be 2 --> links to page 2, 3 --> links to page 3, and the hyphen that is a "neutral" symbol.

For example, what I get now is:

**List of Figures**

1. A result that requires two pages. (cont.)  2
2. A result that requires two pages 3

while I would like to have:

**List of Figures**

1. A result that requires two pages 2-3

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[scale=.9]{fig1}}
\\
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[scale=.9]{fig2}}
\caption{A result that requires two pages. \emph{(cont.)}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[scale=.9]{fig3}}
\\
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[scale=.9]{fig4}}
\caption{A result that requires two pages.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you meant `hyperref` and not `cleveref`? After all, hyperlinks are created by the former.

Comment: I have never seen a range of page numbers in the List of *whatever*; only the first page. For instance, you don't see "First Chapter ... 1–42" in the ToC.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply use an empty optional argument for `\caption` in the continuation (and the optional argument in the first `\caption` if you want to get rid of "(cont)" in the list of figures):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig1}}
\\
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig2}}
\caption[A result that requires two pages.]{A result that requires two pages. \emph{(cont.)}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig3}}
\\
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig4}}
\caption[]{A result that requires two pages.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I changed some of the settings so that the example will fit in just one page.

I originally didn't see the requirement concerning the page numbering in the LoF; here's now a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}

\def\myaddcontentsline#1#2#3{%
\addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\thepage--\finalpage}}}

\gdef\finalatpage#1{\global\def\finalpage{#1}}
\finalatpage{0}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\MyCaption[1]{%
  \myaddcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}#1}}
  \newcommand\savefinalpage{\makeatletter
  \write\@auxout{\protect\finalatpage{\arabic{page}}}
  \makeatother}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig1}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig2}}
  \caption{A result that requires two pages. \emph{(cont.)}}
  \MyCaption{A result that requires two pages}
\end{figure}

\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig3}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig4}}
  \caption{A result that requires two pages.}
  \savefinalpage
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now another version with the new requirements; in particular, it requires loading `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[linktocpage,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\myaddcontentsline#1#2#3{%
\addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}%
    {\protect\hyperlink{xyzs}{\thepage}--\protect\hyperlink{xyzf}{\finalpage}}{}}%
}%

\gdef\finalatpage#1{\gdef\finalpage{#1}}
\finalatpage{0}

\def\MyCaption#1{\hypertarget{xyzs}{}%
  \myaddcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}#1}%
}

\def\savefinalpage{\hypertarget{xyzf}{}\makeatletter
  \write\@auxout{\protect\finalatpage{\arabic{page}}}
  \makeatother
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig1}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig2}}
  \caption{A result that requires two pages. \emph{(cont.)}}
  \MyCaption{A result that requires two pages}
\end{figure}

\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig3}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig4}}
  \caption{A result that requires two pages.}
  \savefinalpage
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

A new version that improves the anchoring of the hyperlink for the continuation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[linktocpage,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\myaddcontentsline#1#2#3{%
\addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{\ignorespaces #3}%
    {\protect\hyperlink{xyzs}{\thepage}--\protect\hyperlink{xyzf}{\finalpage}}{}}%
}%

\gdef\finalatpage#1{\gdef\finalpage{#1}}
\finalatpage{0}

\def\MyCaption#1{\hypertarget{xyzs}{}%
  \myaddcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}#1}%
}

\def\savefinalpage{\makeatletter
  \write\@auxout{\protect\finalatpage{\arabic{page}}}
  \makeatother
}

\def\MyCaptionE#1{\caption[#1]{\hypertarget{xyzf}{#1}}%
  \savefinalpage
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig1}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig2}}
  \caption{A result that requires two pages. \emph{(cont.)}}
  \MyCaption{A result that requires two pages}
\end{figure}

\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage
\begin{figure}
  \caption{test}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!b]
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig3}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig4}}
  \MyCaptionE{A result that requires two pages.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

#### Remark:

These last two codes deserve some explanation but unfortunately right now I won't be able to provide it. As soon as I can I will do so.

Comment: Hi @Gonzalo, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, your solution doesn't fulfill completely my request.
If the first subfigure starts, say, at page 5 and the last one is at page 8, I want the List of Figures to explicitly report "5-8". With the code you proposed, it would write only the page of the first subfigure, that is "5".

Comment: @mp87: I am working on it. I'll let you know when I post an update.

Comment: @mp87:please see my updated answer.

Comment: Your solution is nice, but I need to use it in a document that is more complex than the example I provided. I'll update my first post to add more info. The problem I that your code writes this row inside the .lof file:
`\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}A result that requires two pages.}{2--4}`
while usually it should be:
`\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{A result that requires two pages.}{2--4}{figure.caption.1}`
The second problem is that I would like to have a link to the two pages, that is 2 --> figure.caption.1, 4 --> figure.caption.2.

Comment: @mp87: see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent work! There's only a little thing left to fix: the line inside the .lof file is `\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}A result that requires two pages.}{\hyperlink {xyzs}{2}--\hyperlink {xyzf}{4}}{}` while it should be `\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{A result that requires two pages.}{\hyperlink {xyzs}{figure.caption.1}--\hyperlink {xyzf}{figure.caption.2}}{}` (notice also the additional left brace in the latter). At the moment, the code just redirect to the page of the figure, but not at the figure's actual position.

Comment: @mp87: no; with your suggestion, the texts "figure.caption.1" and "figure.caption.2" will appear in the list of figures right after the each page number; perhaps the last argument could be used, but I don't see clearly how since there would be two possible values to be used. For the moment, I don't see how to improve the anchoring.

Comment: @mp87: I've added a new version that (I think) improves the anchoring at least for the continuation, but I'd rather use the previous one ;-)

Comment: could you please help me in fixing the problem with the counter? See my post below. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something similar, and found your answer. I don't really like to have to make multiple new definitions every time I want to use this. So I tried to solve it differently. I'm new to this so maybe there's a good reason not to do it the way I suggested...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[linktocpage,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}


\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{continued}{#1~#2~(cont.)}
\captionsetup[ContinuedFloat]{labelformat=continued}

\def\MyCaption#1#2#3{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}{\ignorespaces #1\relax}}{{\pageref{#2}}--{\pageref{#3}}}{}}}


\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig1}
  \caption{A result that requires two pages.}
  \label{fig:part1}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig2}
  \caption{A result that requires two pages.}
  \label{fig:part2}
    \MyCaption{A result that requires two pages}{fig:part1}{fig:part2}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig3}
  \caption{Another result that requires two pages.}
  \label{fig:part3}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig4}
  \caption{Another result that requires two pages.}
  \label{fig:part4}
    \MyCaption{Another result that requires two pages}{fig:part3}{fig:part4}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the range of pages and just want to avoid the multiple entries, just add

```
\captionsetup[ContinuedFloat]{list=false}
```

to the preamble.

Of course this doesn't answer the actual question, but that specific line is what I was trying to google and what brought me to this question. It took me a while to figure out the solution since the other answers are quite convoluted, so I thought I'll leave this here to save fellow googlers a few seconds of their lives.

Answer (score 0):

@Gonzalo: Sorry for the late answer. I hacked a bit your code, and I finally found a satisfying solution. I report it here, in the hope that can be helpful to someone else.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[linktocpage,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\myaddcontentsline#1#2#3#4#5{%
\addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}%
    {\protect\hyperref[#4]{\thepage}--\protect\hyperref[#5]{\finalpage}}{}}%
}

\gdef\finalatpage#1{\gdef\finalpage{#1}}
\finalatpage{0}

\def\MyCaption#1#2#3{%
  \myaddcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}{\ignorespaces #1\relax }}{#2}{#3}%
}

\def\savefinalpage{\makeatletter
  \write\@auxout{\protect\finalatpage{\arabic{page}}}
  \makeatother
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig1}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig2}}
  \caption{A result that requires two pages. \emph{(cont.)}}
  \label{fig:part1}
  \MyCaption{A result that requires two pages}{fig:part1}{fig:part2}
\end{figure}

\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig3}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig4}}
  \caption{A result that requires two pages.}
  \label{fig:part2}
  \savefinalpage
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Basically I substituted the `hypertarget` command with `hyperref` and introduced the target objects in the definition of `myaddcontentsline`. I know that this solution is pretty rough, so please let me know if it is possible to improve it.

#### Edit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[linktocpage,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\gdef\finalatpage#1{\gdef\finalpage{#1}}
\finalatpage{0}
\gdef\finalatpagei#1{\gdef\finalpagei{#1}}
\finalatpagei{0}

\def\MyCaption#1#2#3#4{%
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{figure}{#1}%
    {\protect\hyperref[#2]{\thepage}--\protect\hyperref[#3]{#4}}{}}%
}

\def\savefinalpage{\makeatletter
  \write\@auxout{\protect\finalatpage{\arabic{page}}}
  \makeatother
}
\def\savefinalpagei{\makeatletter
  \write\@auxout{\protect\finalatpagei{\arabic{page}}}
  \makeatother
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig1}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig2}}
  \caption{A result that requires two pages. \emph{(cont.)}}
  \label{fig:part1}
  \MyCaption{A result that requires two pages}{fig:part1}{fig:part2}{\finalpage}
\end{figure}

\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig3}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig4}}
  \caption{A result that requires two pages.}
  \label{fig:part2}
  \savefinalpage
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig1}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig2}}
  \caption{A result that requires two pages. \emph{(cont.)}}
  \label{fig:part3}
  \MyCaption{Another result that requires two pages}{fig:part3}{fig:part4}{\finalpagei}
\end{figure}

\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig3}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig4}}
  \caption{Another result that requires two pages.}
  \label{fig:part4}
  \savefinalpagei
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

#### Edit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[linktocpage,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\gdef\finalatpage#1{\gdef\finalpage{#1}}
\finalatpage{0}
\gdef\finalatpagei#1{\gdef\finalpagei{#1}}
\finalatpagei{0}

\def\MyCaption#1#2#3#4{%
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}{\ignorespaces #1\relax}}%
    {\protect\hyperref[#2]{\thepage}--\protect\hyperref[#3]{#4}}{}}%
}

\def\savefinalpage{\makeatletter
  \write\@auxout{\protect\finalatpage{\arabic{page}}}
  \makeatother
}
\def\savefinalpagei{\makeatletter
  \write\@auxout{\protect\finalatpagei{\arabic{page}}}
  \makeatother
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig1}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig2}}
  \caption{A result that requires two pages. \emph{(cont.)}}
  \label{fig:part1}
  \MyCaption{A result that requires two pages}{fig:part1}{fig:part2}{\finalpage}
\end{figure}

\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig3}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig4}}
  \caption{A result that requires two pages.}
  \label{fig:part2}
  \savefinalpage
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig1}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig2}}
  \caption{A result that requires two pages. \emph{(cont.)}}
  \label{fig:part3}
  \MyCaption{Another result that requires two pages}{fig:part3}{fig:part4}{\finalpagei}
\end{figure}

\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{list=no}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig3}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig4}}
  \caption{Another result that requires two pages.}
  \label{fig:part4}
  \savefinalpagei
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I spoke too soon, there is a problem with the counter defined by `savefinalpage`. Since I am using the code twice, in the second case `\finalpage` is overwritten, and I find it twice in the List of Figures. So what I find is something like:  
1. Figure 1. A results that requires two pages   2-7  
2. Figure 2. A results that requires other two pages   6-7    
while the Figure 1 is covering pages 2 and 3.

Comment: In the edit to your answer I've provided  perhaps not the most elegant solution (it duplicates definitions), but it will produce the desired output. When I have some time I'll try to improve it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thank you! It doesn't matter if it's not elegant, it works like a charm! P.S. I improved slightly the definition of `MyCaption`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add solution with hyperref to have hyperlink in list of figure and section & page added.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks,%
    citecolor=blue,%
    filecolor=blue,%
    linkcolor=orange,%
    urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\makeatletter
\def\myaddcontentsline#1#2#3{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{see \thesection\ at p. \thepage}{\@currentHref}}}
\renewcommand{\@todonotes@addElementToListOfTodos}{%
    \if@todonotes@colorinlistoftodos%
        \myaddcontentsline{tdo}{todo}{{%
            \colorbox{\@todonotes@currentbackgroundcolor}%
                {\textcolor{\@todonotes@currentbackgroundcolor}{o}}%
            \ \@todonotes@caption}}%
    \else%
        \myaddcontentsline{tdo}{todo}{{\@todonotes@caption}}%
    \fi}%
\newcommand*\mylistoftodos{%
  \begingroup
       \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{see 9.9 at p. 99}%
       \renewcommand*\@tocrmarg{\the\wd\@tempboxa}%
       \renewcommand*\@pnumwidth{\the\wd\@tempboxa}%
       \listoftodos%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{My first chapter}
\section{A first section}
\lipsum
\todo{This is a note}
\section{Another section}
\lipsum
\todo{This is another note}

\mylistoftodos
\end{document}
```

explanation with hyperref command addcontentsline is redefined and is taking four parameter.
The fourth parameter must give destination for hyperlink given by @currentHref.

I Thank a lot Ulrike Fischer who help me to solve the main problem with the fourth parameter.
[image]