# How to make a figure continue on the next page

Tags: floats

My code is:

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\title{}
\author{}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[update,prepend]{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
%\usepackage{eulervm}
%\usepackage{iwona}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\raggedbottom

\everymath{\displaystyle} 

\newcommand{\pder}[2][]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}

\renewcommand\textfraction{.1}

\begin{document}

%Figure 
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{\textbf{Bank Joint Probability of Default (\textit{JPoD}), Conditional Joint Probability of Default (\textit{CoJPoD}) and Change in the Conditional Joint Probability of Default ($\Delta$\textit{CoJPoD})} \\  \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont Panel A presents the average joint probability of default of banks sorted by their originating sovereign. Table~\ref{bankabbreviation} provides a list of the originating sovereigns of the 26 banks. Panel B presents conditional joint probability of default of the banking system given the default of the corresponding sovereign listed in the legend. The abbreviations of the sovereigns are listed in Table~\ref{sovcorrelation}. Panel C presents the change in the conditional joint probability of default of the banking system given the default of the corresponding sovereign listed in the legend. The $\Delta$\textit{CoJPoD} of each series is derived by conditioning the bank joint probability of default on the corresponding sovereign listed in the legend and then computing the difference between the \textit{CoJPoD} and the \textit{JPoD}. In all three panels, non-zero correlation matrices are used to derive bank \textit{JPoD}, \textit{CoJPoD} and $\Delta$\textit{CoJPoD}. The non-zero correlation matrices are based on daily changes in the 5-year CDS spreads of sovereign and bank CDS contracts. The sample period for all three panels is from 01/01/2008 to 28/02/2013.}
  \label{bankjpodcojpodDcojpod}

\vspace{0.5 cm}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont Panel A: Bank \textit{JPoD}
\end{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{25.pdf}

\vspace{1 cm}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont Panel B: Bank \textit{CoJPoD}
\end{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{9.pdf}


\end{figure}


%Figure
\begin{figure}
\vspace{-1.8cm}
  \centering
  \caption{\textbf{Bank Joint Probability of Default (\textit{JPoD}), Conditional Joint Probability of Default (\textit{CoJPoD}) and Change in the Conditional Joint Probability of Default ($\Delta$\textit{CoJPoD})}}
  \label{bootstrapbank}

\vspace{0.5 cm}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont Panel C: Bank $\Delta$\textit{CoJPoD}
\end{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{10.pdf}

\vspace{8 cm}

\end{document}
```

The output appears as:

[image]
[image]

Everything is good, however instead of "Figure 6" appearing on the next page, I would like it to say "Figure 5 (Cont.):"  Currently it automatically renames it as a new figure.

How can I do this?

---

EDIT: This is what I have now (with the `subfig` package)

```
%Figure 
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{\textbf{Bank Joint Probability of Default (\textit{JPoD}), Conditional Joint Probability of Default (\textit{CoJPoD}) and Change in the Conditional Joint Probability of Default ($\Delta$\textit{CoJPoD})} \\  \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont Panel A presents the average joint probability of default of the banking system with each of the 10 Euro Area (EA) sovereigns. Panel B presents conditional joint probability of default of the banking system given the default of the corresponding sovereign listed in the legend. Panel C presents the change in the conditional joint probability of default of the banking system given the default of the corresponding sovereign listed in the legend. The $\Delta$\textit{CoJPoD} of each series is derived by conditioning the bank joint probability of default on the corresponding sovereign listed in the legend and then computing the difference between the \textit{CoJPoD} and the \textit{JPoD}. For all three panels, the abbreviations of the sovereigns are listed in Table~\ref{sovereignabbreviation}. Non-zero correlation matrices are used to derive bank \textit{JPoD}, \textit{CoJPoD} and $\Delta$\textit{CoJPoD}. The non-zero correlation matrices are based on daily changes in the 5-year CDS spreads of sovereign and bank CDS contracts. The sample period for all three panels is from 01/01/2008 to 28/02/2013.}
  \label{bankjpodcojpodDcojpod1}

\vspace{0.5 cm}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont Panel A: Bank \textit{JPoD}
\end{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{25.pdf}

\vspace{1 cm}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont Panel B: Bank \textit{CoJPoD}
\end{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{9.pdf}


\end{figure}


%Figure
\begin{figure}
\vspace{-1.8cm}
\ContinuedFloat
  \centering
  \caption{\textbf{Bank Joint Probability of Default (\textit{JPoD}), Conditional Joint Probability of Default (\textit{CoJPoD}) and Change in the Conditional Joint Probability of Default ($\Delta$\textit{CoJPoD})}}
  \label{bankjpodcojpodDcojpod2}

\vspace{0.5 cm}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont Panel C: Bank $\Delta$\textit{CoJPoD}
\end{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{10.pdf}

\vspace{8 cm}


\end{figure}
```

Strangely, the figure where I used `\continuedfloat` is named as "Figure 4" and the figure following it is now renamed to Figure 5 (instead of staying as Figure 6), the output is:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Furthermore, I would like to have word (Cont.) before the colon, so that the continued figure is named as Figure 5 (Cont.): rather than Figure 5: (Cont.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `subfig` command has a `\ContinuedFloat` command (you could use subfig for your individual images as well, look for example at

[One caption in listoffigures for a ContinuedFloat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50988/one-caption-in-listoffigures-for-a-continuedfloat)

Comment: After I add \ContinuedFloat the figure is renamed as Figure 4 rather than Figure 5 (Cont.): 

Also the next figure is renamed to Figure 5 instead of staying as Figure 6