# Create one figure spread across two pages

Tags: graphics, floats, wide-image

I have a **huge** figure, approx 2000 pixels width and 9000 pixels height (approx -- just to give an idea).

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \ContinuedFloat
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.2]{model.png}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
```

The problem is, even with a scale of 0.2, it is not fitting on the page. I can go further, and scale it down even more, but if I do so, it'll become totally unreadable.

Since it doesn't fit in the page, the bottom part of the image is cut-off. Is there any way I can spread my image across two pages so that no info is lost?

I looked at posts like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132211/how-to-make-a-figure-continue-on-the-next-page), but they deal with more than one figures (sub-figures), while I only have a single image. Any help would be great. Thanks...

Comment: if it is a big figure don't use `[!htb]` !!! as the main effect of that is to omit `p` so prevent it being on a page with just figures, and specifying latex had to leave room for text on the page as well. You want exactly the opposite  `[p]`. Just split the image in two using an image editor then two `[p]` figures will appear on adjacent pages.

Comment: You can use [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22836/194703) to split the image. Presumably a `breakable` `tcolorbox` will also work. Or just use the `trimclip` package to do appropriate clips.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat got it, thank you :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't know about it.Thanks :)